# How to solve parallel processing of only a part of the code in Python?

Tags: python, parallel-processing, python-multiprocessing

I'm pretty much new to this topic so I'm sorry if what I'm asking is sort of trivial. I have a long `main` function and would like to parallelize only a piece of that.

**What does the `main` function do?** First it reads in the content of a directory from a given path, collects all the files into a list, opens up them one after the other and parses their content according to previously defined patterns, groups the obtained data together, inserts it into database and finally makes some output messages to the screen about the number and type of data inserted.

**Why do I want parallel processing?** As I ran the code I realized it is extremely slow. (It takes usually 7-8 sec to process one single file which is, given that I have several thousands of these files, is quite a lot.) The most time-consuming processes are: parsing, grouping the data and inserting into database. So my idea was to put these into a new function (as I've learnt from the Python documentation that processes to be parallelized are generally placed into a new function) and try to get the CPU to process it parallelly. So practically what I want to parallel-process is a long for loop that goes through all files of the directory. This part of the code lies in the middle of `main`.

**How did I want to achieve it?** I imported `multiprocessing.Pool` library. Although I didn't know what to do with the `if __name__ == '__main__'` part. I've seen this structure (e.g.: [1](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html)) in the documentations and read pooling is not working properly without this. But all those examples were only pure multiprocessing examples, not containing any other processes. That's why I was puzzled how to move forward.

The only part I would like to parallelize is a method called `toParallel()` which consists of the aforementioned processes, i.e.: parsing, grouping and inserting.

I had two ideas: 1) To get rid of my `main` function and replace it by `if __name__ == '__main__'` structure. Didn't really work and caused an enormous amount of errors that needed to be corrected. 
2) To keep the `main` but also create `if __name__ == '__main__'` after that, and write pooling inside its block (see the code snippet below). The `main` is called before `if __name__ == '__main__'`. This didn't throw an error, so I suppose this might be the right direction. But I don't have any results yet when I try to print out the content of `outdata` by: `print(outdata.get())`.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = Pool(4)
    outdata = pool.map(toParallel, (database, fileList,))
    pool.join()
    pool.close()
```

**Edit** This is clearly not correct though, because my `main` function continues after insertion is finished. As I mentioned above, there is some console output messages that are based on information about the freshly inserted (or not inserted) data. But if I call my `toParallel` function from the end, the compiler will not give meaningful data about the end of `main` function.

**Edit 2** For ShadowRanger's recommendation I typed the following snippet inside `main`, at the place of the process that I want to parallelize:

```
with Pool() as pool:
    results = pool.map(toParallel, (database, fileList))
    pool.join()
    pool.close()
```

But it returned the following error: `TypeError: toParallel() missing 1 required positional argument: fileList`. Even though it is included in the argument list above.

Any type of help is greatly appreciated. If you can recommend something to read, apart from the general documentations, that's fine as well. Thank you for your help.

Comment: The call to `main` should occur within the `if __name__ == '__main__':`  block, not above it. The idea is that the `if __name__ == '__main__':` only executes once, when the module is the entry point; on Windows, if you fail to protect the call to `main` with that guard, when `multiprocessing` imports the main module in each worker (to simulate a fork-like behavior), it will run `main` in each of them (usually not the goal).

Comment: If you need to parallelize something, create and use the `Pool` *inside* `main` for the appropriate tasks. For example, replacing a `list` comprehension like `results = [do_foo(x) for x in inputs]` with `with Pool() as pool: results = pool.map(do_foo, inputs)` would perform the `do_foo` calls in parallel. Note: This will only improve performance if the cost of each `do_foo` call is high enough to offset the cost of pickling `do_foo` itself, plus its arguments and return values; if the IPC costs exceed the CPU costs of processing the data, you gain nothing.

Comment: Thank you for the tip @ShadowRanger. I emptied `if __name__ == '__main__'` and only put `main()` inside. Also I rolled back to the process to be parallelized, and wrote you recommended. A strange error popped up though (please see the code snippet above in the Edit 2)

`TypeError: toParallel() missing 1 required positional argument: fileList`

Comment: Sounds like `toParallel` takes two arguments; you're passing it one at a time. I'm guessing you want to pass the same `database` to each call, and a different entry from `fileList`? If so, you'd want something like `pool.starmap(toParallel, zip(itertools.repeat(database), fileList))`, where using `itertools.repeat` gets you the same database argument each time, and `starmap` unpacks the results of the `zip` so each call to `toParallel` takes the same `database`, and a new value from `fileList`. Please provide a [MCVE] that includes the prototype of `toParallel` and how it uses the arguments.